# Parametrize tests for similar types

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have an interface `A` that's implemented by two types `B1` and `B2`. I want to write a test suite that checks that both `B1` and `B2` implement `A` correctly. Say is of the form

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, from_object): pass
    def do_something(self): pass
```

and `B1`, `B2` inherit fro `A`. My test looks something like

```
class TestA:
    @pytest.fixture(params=[input1, input2])
    def some_data(request):
        return T(request.param)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("with_object", [pytest.lazy_fixture("some_data")])
    def test_do_something(with_object):
        assert with_object.do_something() == expectation
```

I'd like to have that `T` attains `B1` and `B2`, but I am not sure how to achieve that nicely. Do you have hints on that?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd achieve this but using `indirect=True` to pass parameters (in your case 2 different classes) to `some_data` fixture which could then access it from `request.param` and return an initialized object:

```py
class TestA:
    @pytest.fixture()
    def some_data(self, request):
        return request.param()

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("some_data", (B1, B2), indirect=True)
    def test_do_something(self, some_data):
        assert some_data.do_something() == expectation
```

This assumes that `some_data()` would do a more complex intialization of `B1`/`B2` than in my example because you actually wouldn't need the fixture otherwise. If the fixture needs some additional parametrized data, you could make the input params more complex:

```py
class TestA:
    @pytest.fixture()
    def some_data(self, request):
        return request.param[0](request.param[1])

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "some_data",
        ((B1, {'abc': 'xyz'}), (B2, {'abc': 'xyz'})),
        indirect=True
    )
    def test_do_something(self, some_data):
        assert some_data.do_something() == expectation
```